# How do I write the mathematical equation for ARIMA(0,0,5)(1,0,1) period 12?

Tags: arima, model

I would appreciate if someone could help me write the mathematical equation for the seasonal ARIMA (0,0,5) x (1,0,1) period 12. I'm a little confused with how to go about this.